# Android: why my class is still obfuscated though proguarded

Tags: java, android, proguard

In the package, /ui/cinema/model/, there are several classes I didn't want them to be obfuscated, so i declare the following lines in my proguard config file:

> -keep public class com.example.ui.cinema.model.** {*;}
>
> -keep public class com.example.ui.cinema.model.**$* {*;}

For most of the classes in that foler, it's working fine, except "CinemaCityModel":

```
package com.example.ui.cinema.model;
public class CinemaCityModel
{
    public static final String CUR_CITY_NAME_SORT="CURRENT";
    public static final String HOT_CITY_NAME_SORT="HOT";

    private String CityId;
    private String CityName; 
    private String NameSort; 

    public String getCityId()
    {
        return CityId;
    }

    public void setCityId(String cityId)
    {
        CityId = cityId;
    }

    public String getCityName()
    {
        return CityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName)
    {
        CityName = cityName;
    }

    public String getNameSort()
    {
        return NameSort;
    }

    public void setNameSort(String nameSort)
    {
        NameSort = nameSort;
    }

}
```

I anti-compiled the apk, and cannot find CinemaCityModel. But it's in that package in my sourcecode. It's obfuscated and i dont know why. Anyone met this? Please help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The `-keep` keyword in proguard only prevents the class from being optimized away if it is unused.

To prevent a class from being obfuscated, you need to use `-dontobfuscate`

Comment: Thanks, sddamico. But after check the Proguard Manual, it says "Specifies not to obfuscate the input class files. By default, obfuscation is applied; classes and class members receive new short random names, except for the ones listed by the various -keep options. Internal attributes that are useful for debugging, such as source files names, variable names, and line numbers are removed."....So I think my CinemaCityModel should not be obfuscated. What's interesting is, the other class in that package applies to this rule, except the CinemaCityModel..

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration indeed preserves this class (in fact the first line is sufficient, since it implies the second line). You should see it listed in proguard/seeds.txt.

You should double-check: maybe it is missing from the input as well, because it isn't compiled properly. Or in this case, maybe it isn't public or it is in a different package after all. Or maybe your decompiler fails to write out the decompiled class.